# React State vs. Props - Why are state changes not reflected in components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a div that sits underneath the main app (lexically) but is styled to only show up after a timed delay.   I feel like this is most likely a very simple failure on my part to grasp some of the react concepts I'm working with.

Here's my code: (The CSS is pseudo code)

```
import React, {Component} from 'React'; //eslint-disable-line
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ReactTimeout from 'react-timeout';

const Icon = styled.div.attrs({
  dataRight: props => props.dataRight || '1em',
  dataLeft: props => props.dataLeft || '1em',
  displayIcons: props => props.displayIcons|| 'none'

})`
    display: ${props => props.displayIcons};
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: ${props => props.dataRight};
    left: ${props => props.dataLeft};
`;



class Iconset extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayIcons: 'none'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.setTimeout(this.showIcons, 4000);
    alert('Display Icons =  ' + this.state.displayIcons);
  }

  showIcons() {  
    this.setState({displayIcons: 'Block'}); 
    alert('Display Icons =  ' + this.state.displayIcons);
  }   

  render () {
    return ( 
      <div id='iconset'>
        <Icon dataLeft="auto" dataRight="1em" display={this.props.displayIcons}>First Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
        <Icon dataLeft="1em" dataRight="auto" display={this.props.displayIcons}>Second Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ReactTimeout(Iconset);
```

So, my current understanding is that when the timeout fires the container state change should populate down to the children and override the display: none with display: block.  That change never seems to happen although the state-change itself does happen.

What concept am I missing here?

Comment: one hint is to add ´debugger' into your code and opening the developers tool see the variables values in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use setState, you're setting the `displayIcons` variable in component's internal state which would be accessed by `this.state.displayIcons`.

If you look at your render, in the display prop, you're targeting `this.props.displayIcons`

You would only use props here if you were changing the `displayIcons` property in a parent component.

Change that to `this.state.displayIcons` and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Also, worth noting that the function called within the timeout needed to be bound to `this`.  I was somewhat surprised . by that, but it seems that ownership gets muddy somewhere in there.

Comment: Oh yes, I was going to point that out but you said the setState was working correctly.

handy ways of doing it: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: Initial testing seemed to cloud the issue as I was setting and testing in the same place.  Once I was testing in a new location the gap became obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what makes sense or not to your code.

```
this.props.setTimeout(this.showIcons, 4000);
```

Is setTimeout really a props function? It looks like that what you really want was to just call setTimeOut:

```
setTimeout(this.showIcons, 4000);
```

Why are you rendering props.displayIcons ?

```
<Icon dataLeft="auto" dataRight="1em" display={this.props.displayIcons}>First Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
<Icon dataLeft="1em" dataRight="auto" display={this.props.displayIcons}>Second Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
```

I believe what you really want is to render the state that you changed on timeOut:

```
<Icon dataLeft="auto" dataRight="1em" display={this.state.displayIcons}>First Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
<Icon dataLeft="1em" dataRight="auto" display={this.state.displayIcons}>Second Icon</Icon> {/*eslint-disable-line */}
```

Hope that helps!